# How can i get the inputted text in a textfield from another frame to the 2nd frame?

Tags: java

Here is the syntax... on the first frame

```
JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
```

from the bottom there has the actionListener

```
this.setVisible(false);
new Display().setVisible(true);
```

Now on the 2nd Frame i want to create a text field that automatically display the one I typed in the textfield on first frame. (but when I try to call the tf1 variable, it cannot be resolved.)

Comment: `JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();`  - very useful code snippet  *(sarcasm)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain an object reference to the textfield you want to get the text from and also the one you want to copy the text to, and then the methods `getText()` and `setText()` will do what you require.

If you need more help, I suggest you add some more specific details to your question, perhaps along with some example code.

How about this suggestion:

1. subclass frame, call the class something like TextFrame
2. add a constructor to TextFrame that adds a new field that is the textField you are going to edit, called `theTextField`
3. add a method to TextFrame named `public String getText()` that gets the text from theTextField when it is called
4. add a method to TextFrame named `public void setText(String text)` that sets the text in theTextField when it is called
5. from your main class, create a new TextFrame instance named inputTextFrame and one named outputTextFrame
6. then call getText on the inputTextFrame and pass this string to the `outputTextFrame.setText()`

When you want to call the last point is up to the business logic of your application

Comment: how is that? i can't call the textfield from the 1st frame to 2nd frame? it is cannot be resolved.

Comment: Here is the syntax... on the first frame 

JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();


from the bottom there has the actionListener

this.setVisible(false);
new Display().setVisible(true);


Now on the 2nd Frame i want to create a text field that automatically display the one i typed in the textfield on first frame. (but when i try to call the tf1 variable, it cannot be resolved.)

Comment: You can edit your question, stick this code in your question, you can format it better there.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me an idea =)